# how to use permutation and combination to arrange girls and boys?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I couldn't find anything close enough to this, but if you know somewhere that does please leave a comment about it.

In how many ways can a doubles game of tennis be arranged from nine boys and eleven girls if each side must have one boy and one girl?

Answer (score 1):

$2{9 \choose 2}{11 \choose 2}$

Pick 2 boys and 2 girls, and how many mixed games can you make of those 4?
2, right?

Comment: the correct answer should be 3960, but I have no idea how to do the math for it. the solution you gave me only came out to be being 3240

Comment: You didn't calculate my solution right, 2*(9*8/2)*(11*10/2)=72*11*10/2=36*11*10=3960